# Invalid config logstash file

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I'm following a basic tutorial since i'm new in this, and i've the following config file:

```
input {  
  file {
    path => "D:\elastic\logstash\data\data.csv"
    start_position => "beginning"    
  }
}
filter {  
  csv {
      separator => ","
      columns => ["Date","Open","High","Low","Close","Volume","Adj Close"]
  }
  mutate {convert =&gt; ["High", "float"]}
  mutate {convert =&gt; ["Open", "float"]}
  mutate {convert =&gt; ["Low", "float"]}
  mutate {convert =&gt; ["Close", "float"]}
  mutate {convert =&gt; ["Volume", "float"]}
}
output {  
    elasticsearch {
        action => "index"
        host => "localhost"
        index => "stock"
        workers => 1
    }
    stdout {}
}
```

And then I execute the following command in the terminal

```
bin\logstash -f logstash-simple.conf
```

And it prints this:

```
io/console not supported; tty will not be manipulated
←[31mfetched an invalid config {:config=>"input {  \n  file {\n    path => \"D:\
\elastic\\logstash\\data\\data.csv\"\n    start_position => \"beginning\"    \n
 }\n}\nfilter {  \n  csv {\n      separator => \",\"\n      columns => [\"Date\"......
```

And the rest of the file parsed. 
What am I missing?
It's in UTF-8 and tried EOL UNIX and Windows format with both failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify your `file` input like this:

```
  file {
    path => "D:\\elastic\\logstash\\data\\data.csv"
    start_position => "beginning"    
  }
```

or like this

```
  file {
    path => "D:/elastic/logstash/data/data.csv"
    start_position => "beginning"    
  }
```

Also in your filters, there are typos in the `mutate/convert`. They should be like this (i.e. replace `=&gt;` by `=>`):

```
  mutate {convert => ["High", "float"]}
  mutate {convert => ["Open", "float"]}
  mutate {convert => ["Low", "float"]}
  mutate {convert => ["Close", "float"]}
  mutate {convert => ["Volume", "float"]}
```

Comment: Tried both. None did worked. Also in the end of the log, it also says this: The signal HUP is in use by the JVM and will not work correctly on this platform

Comment: Also the `=&gt;` should read `=>` instead. Please fix and try again.

Comment: Replace the =&gt; with =>   ?

Comment: Did that and now I've different error log. See https://codeshare.io/J4j1q

Comment: Try to use forward slashes preferably

Comment: Not really, I'm having problems with parsing the date. In my data, the format is 2015-04-02 and the elasticsearch can't parse it.

Comment: That's another issue, you shouldn't be receiving the same error anymore, though. can you confirm?

Comment: Yes, this is another issue. The one from the filename format is corrected. Thank you

Comment: Awesome, let's tackle the next one ;)

Comment: Ok, so my data format is this:

https://codeshare.io/TggZu

The columns Open to Adj Close don't have any problem, the problem is the date, which I can't parse it.

Comment: Please create a new question with that as that's a different issue.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38793262/cant-parse-date-in-logstash