# Can't parse date in logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I need to parse my Date and it gives me an error.

```
input {  
  file {
    path => "/home/osboxes/ELK/logstash/data/data.csv"
    start_position => "beginning"    
  }
}
filter {  
  csv {
      separator => ","
      columns => ["Date","Open","High","Low","Close","Volume","Adj Close"]
  }


  mutate {convert => ["High", "float"]}
  mutate {convert => ["Open", "float"]}
  mutate {convert => ["Low", "float"]}
  mutate {convert => ["Close", "float"]}
  mutate {convert => ["Volume", "float"]}
}

output {  
    elasticsearch {
        action => "index"
        hosts => "localhost:9200"
        index => "stock"
        workers => 1
    }
    stdout {}
}
```

The data.csv when I'm reading this is like this:

```
Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume,Adj Close
2015-04-02,125.03,125.56,124.19,125.32,32120700,125.32
2015-04-01,124.82,125.12,123.10,124.25,40359200,124.25
```

Where am I missing? Thanks in advance.

My logstash terminal only say this:

```
$ bin/logstash -f /home/osboxes/ELK/logstash/logstash.conf 
Settings: Default pipeline workers: 2
Pipeline main started
```

Comment: What error? Don't see any errors.

Comment: Edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

Add a date statement to the filter:

```
date {
    match => [ "Date", "YYYY-MM-dd" ]
}
```

Comment: Nothing happens. It just says "Settings: Default pipeline workers: 2
Pipeline main started" and that's it.

Comment: `YYYY` should be `yyyy`. You also need to add new data to your CSV file or set the `sincedb_path => "/dev/null"` in your file input

Comment: Did that and this happened. "Failed parsing date from field {:field=>"Date", :value=>"Date", :exception=>"Invalid format: \"Date\"", :config_parsers=>"yyyy-MM-dd", :config_locale=>"default=en_GB", :level=>:warn}" I'm running it in verbose mode.

Comment: It's no big deal, it's simply because it parses the header line as a data line and `Date` is not a valid date. You can ignore that issue or add an `if/drop` filter to get rid of that first event.